# How to completely export and import WordPress?

Tags: import, export

I exported all posts of a WordPress blog. Then I imported the xml file to another WordPress blog. When I tried to search few posts in the new blog, which are in the old blog, I did not find anything. When I opened the xml file, I found that it's incomplete. The file contains `14,226` lines of code. The size of the file is 1.2 MB. I used default tool of WordPress to export and import.

How to export complete list of posts and then import the same?

I have another lame idea to do this, if I don't get any good solution. I can delete the posts which are exported and then export again. But this is a stupid time taking process.

Answer (score 2):

To copy a WordPress install from A to B, do an SQL dump on site A, and restore it to site B. Then search and replace the DB to swap the old URLs for the new URLs. Make sure to copy over the uploads folder in wp-content.

To do the search replace, consider using a tool such as this:

https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: and/or this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search-regex/

Comment: @Tom J Nowell 
I posted a question for a simillar situation but I needed to import 2 sites into one. I hope I can still do this same way. I have a question about featured image, does the sql dump has path to the featured image for each post as well? In general how the featured image works. Is it part of the post content table?
please advise.

Comment: Each of those questions could easily be asked as a question rather than in a comment. I suggest you do so rather than deprive yourself of reputation and quality answers

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the WP Migrate DB plugin
2. Enter new server path and site address
3. Export database
4. Create a new DB and import the database SQL file
5. Download the files and change the wp-config.php database connection details with the new details from the new DB
6. Upload the files to the new installation

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks again. I am trying what you suggested.  In my case, I am going to use a different theme and I see that this migrate plug in copy the theme name to the path. Is that something I can change once migrated?

Comment: Yes. Changing themes is very simple